# Center of Mass of an Orange Slice

Tags: integration, physics

In a question in the book *Advanced Problems in Mathematics* by Stephen Siklos, the reader is told to assume that the center of mass of a spherical ‘segment’ (orange slice) of radius $a$ subtending an angle $2\theta$ at the vertical axis passing through the sphere’s center lies at a distance $$\frac{3\pi a\sin\theta}{16\theta}$$ from the axis. I have tried an unusual way to get to this expression, but have ended up at a different expression:

Say the orange slice is such that the axis passing through the center lies along the $X$-axis with the origin at the sphere’s center and the $Y$-axis directed from the axis to orange’s surface. I then consider infinitesimal orange slices of radius $a$  subtending angle $d\alpha$ at the axis, and sum up the product of their masses and the $Y$-coordinate of their centers of mass, as there is no $X$-component of the COM of our original orange slice.

Let $\gamma(\alpha)$ be the function that takes in the angle subtended and returns the distance of COM of any orange slice of radius $a$ from its axis. I arrive at the following: $$\gamma(2\theta) = \frac{\int_{-\theta}^{\theta} \gamma(d\alpha) \cos \alpha \ dm }{\int dm} =  \frac{\gamma(d\alpha)}{2\theta} \int_{-\theta}^{\theta} \cos \alpha \ d\alpha$$ I then think of $\gamma(d\alpha)$ as $\lim_{\alpha\to0} \gamma(\alpha)=\frac{4a}{3\pi}$ which is the semicircular disc case, so $$\gamma(2\theta) = \frac{4a\sin\theta}{3\pi \theta} $$ Clearly, something has gone wrong. Can someone guide me on where my error(s) are?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Speaking intuitively, an orange slice has variable thickness, null at the axis and large at the surface. It is a wedge taken from a sphere.

Therefore you can not treat it as a "book", although semi-circular, slightly opened and sum the barycenters of the flat (instead of "wedged") "pages" fanning out.

*--- addendum in reply to your comment  ---*

$\gamma(\alpha)=\frac{4a}{3\pi}$ is the centroid of a "flat" semicircle, you cannot use that to "build" the orange slice.
That of a thin wedged slice will be more external, since there it is relatively more thick.

Comment: But doesn’t my method sum the *wedged* smaller slices contained in the larger slice? Perhaps you mean I cannot take $\gamma(d\alpha)$ to represent a semicircle?

Comment: @Tavish: added a note in reply

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
$\ds{}$

---

\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\displaystyle%
\int_{-\theta}^{\theta}\int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{a}
r\sin\pars{\xi}\cos\pars{\phi}\,
r^{2}\sin\pars{\xi}\,\dd r\,\dd\xi\,\dd\phi \over
\displaystyle
\int_{-\theta}^{\theta}\int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{a}
r^{2}\sin\pars{\xi}\,\dd r\,\dd\xi\,\dd\phi}
\\[5mm] = &\
{\pars{a^{4}/4}\pars{\pi/2}\bracks{2\sin\pars{\theta}} \over
\pars{a^{3}/3}\pars{2}\pars{2\theta}} =
\bbx{{3\pi \over 16}\,{\sin\pars{\theta} \over \theta}\, a} \\ &
\end{align}